# Reversing/Debugging - Identifying symlinks in applications

Tags: linux, debugging, reverse-engineering

I was wondering, is there any guidlines for identifying symlink related function in an application binary?

Let's take `BusyBox` for example, `/bin/ping` is a symlink to `/bin/BusyBox`.
How can I know identify the `ping` related functions within the `BusyBox` binary?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't generally do that.

In case of BusyBox, it checks upon startup which commandline was invoked to execute the binary (including the path to the binary itself). It then calls functions that provide the functionality that was selected based on the basename of the binary / symlink.

Again in case of BusyBox, most of the times the funktion names are closely related to the command name. But this is basically just coincidence: it could well be that someone created an exectable "A" that would call a function "X" when started via a symlink name "B" and function "Y" when called as "C".